# Is everything in Tensorflow implemented as a NN?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, unsupervised-learning

For example, Kmeans clustering - is it implemented as a neural network algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

No, why should it ? In order to better understand tensorflow take a look at the original [paper](http://download.tensorflow.org/paper/whitepaper2015.pdf) in the abstract it states:

> TensorFlow [1] is an interface for expressing machine learning
>   algorithms, and an implementation for executing such algorithms. A
>   computation expressed using TensorFlow can be executed with little or
>   no change on a wide variety of heterogeneous systems, ranging from
>   mobile devices such as phones and tablets up to large-scale
>   distributed systems of hundreds of machines and thousands of
>   computational devices such as GPU cards.

Hence Tensorflow is a tool to express algorithms and to schedule them on pieces of hardware such as CPU's, GPU's, TPU's and friends. Because it is most well known for running neural networks doesn't mean that even the simplest things should be implemented by using them.